# Grouping gradle dependencies

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

Is there a way of grouping gradle dependencies?

If I have something like:

```
implementation(group = "A", name = "a", version = "1.0")
implementation(group = "A", name = "b", version = "1.0")
implementation(group = "A", name = "c", version = "1.0")
```

Is there a way of grouping them like:

```
implementation(group = "A", names = [
(name = "a", version = "1.0"),
(name = "b", version = "1.0"),
(name = "c", version = "1.0")
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Write an extension function for `DependencyHandlerScope`:

```
fun DependencyHandlerScope.someDependencyGroup() {
    "implementation"("A:a:1.0")
    "implementation"("A:b:1.0")
    "implementation"("A:c:1.0")
}
```

Add it in the `dependencies` block in your `build.gradle.kts`:

```
dependencies {
    someDependencyGroup()
}
```

Alternatively, you could also write the extension for `DependencyHandler` like this:

```
fun DependencyHandler.someDependencyGroup() {
   add("implementation", "A:a:1.0")
   ...
}
```